# MAC NEURON-Python: Error A newer Command Line Tools release is available. Update them from Software Update in the App Store

Tags: python, macos, neuron-simulator

When trying to [install NEURON with Python support (eg. can run `python -c "import neuron"`), using instructions from the Human Brain Project portal website](https://bbp.epfl.ch/nmc-portal/web/guest/tools#NeuronHomebrew). After running:

`brew install neuron`

I get the following (misleading) error:

> Error: A newer Command Line Tools release is available. Update them from Software Update in the App Store.

However, the App Store does not list "Command Line Tools". How do I update the "Command Line Tools"?*

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going to the App Store, as the message suggests, update the Command Tools from terminal.

1. List all packages with `softwareupdate --list` in terminal. May take a minute.
2. Copy the name of the Command Line Tools package** after the `*` (e.g. mine was `* Command Line Tools (macOS Sierra version 10.12) for Xcode-8.3` )
3. Install the latest package with e.g. `sudo softwareupdate --install "Command Line Tools (macOS Sierra version 10.12) for Xcode-8.3"` (note the quotes). May take a while too, but you should see network activity in Activity Monitor, while the download takes place.

In my opinion, the [easiest way to install NEURON+Python on MacOS has been this tutorial by M. Hines](https://www.neuron.yale.edu/ftp/neuron/nrn_mac_install.pdf). The instructions on the HBP portal led to the above error and several others later. Even that tutorial requires the Command Line Tools, so the answer above was still helpful.